# For Loop not working

Tags: javascript

I want this function to add the two values inputted from the form but instead of adding the values it merges the number. If I input 2 and 2 it comes 22, whereas I want 4 to be outputted. I take it that the for loop is not wotking

```
<script>
var calculate = function(){
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var length = input.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  input[i] = input[i].value;
  input[i] = parseInt(input[i]);
}
var total_living_room = input[0] + input[1];
document.getElementById("sh").innerHTML=total_living_room;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `input[0]` and `input[1]` is Still a Element and you must add the value by `parseInt(input[0].value) + parseInt(input[1].value)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that `getElementsByTagName()` returns a NodeList and no array (see,e.g., [MDN on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)).

Both behave similar in many ways, but the elements of a NodeList can not be changed in the way you do.

As a solution parse your values in a second array and use that:

```
<script>
var calculate = function(){
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
      length = input.length,
      inputVals = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    inputVals.push( parseInt( input[i].value, 10 ) );
  }
  var total_living_room = inputVals[0] + inputVals[1];
  document.getElementById("sh").innerHTML=total_living_room;
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9xGz/)

Comment: @user2197789 Added fiddle and fixed an error within the loop (was PHP syntax there). Remember that this currently has no input validation, so `NaN` can still occur on wrong inputs!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to overwrite the input dom element in the array with the value it carries? Change to:

```
var cache = [];
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    cache.push(parseInt(input[i].value, 10));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your code `input[0]` and `input[1]` is **Still a Element** and you must add its value like below

```
parseInt(input[0].value) + parseInt(input[1].value)
```

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/145/